# C - Finding three numbers to add to a target value using concurrent threads

Tags: c, multithreading

I'm doing a C project where I have to read 10000 lines of arbitrary integers from a text file into an array and find three integers that add to a target value. It then prints out the time taken to find the values.

For example - if my target is 233, the three numbers could be 81/102/50. That is if those numbers are found in the text file.

I created three nested for loops to find every combination of the 10000 integers. It took me about 5 minutes, without any use of threads.

My project involves implementing concurrent threads and I am having trouble figuring out a faster method to find the numbers.

I thought about splitting the array in half, where one thread finds a combination from 0-5000 and the other 5000-10000 but I realized it wouldn't work since the three numbers could be in either half. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Start by sorting the array. Then, instead of three nested loops, you can use two nested loops and a binary search. The two nested loops find every sum of two numbers. Once you have the sum of two numbers, the third number must be equal to the target value minus that sum. So you can do a binary search to determine whether that third number exists in the array.

The speed of the new algorithm can be estimated as follows. The three nested loops compute `10000 choose 3` sums, which is 167 billion sums. That's about 500 million sums per second (given that your run time was 5 minutes).

The two nested loops compute `10000 choose 2` partial sums. That's 50 million partial sums. For each of those partial sums, the code needs to perform a binary search, which takes at most `ceil(log_2(10000)) = 14` comparisons. So the total number of comparisons is 700 million.

The result is that you replace 167 billion sums with 700 million comparisons. Assuming that the comparisons are more expensive than the sums, you're looking at a running time of about 4 seconds, even without concurrent threads.

To add concurrency, simply divide the array by the number of processor cores that you have. (It's important to note here that if you have more threads than cores, then the threads aren't really running concurrently.)  The outer loop of each thread only uses a portion of the array. The inner loop of the thread scans the whole array to compute the partial sum. Then the thread does the binary search to see if the third number exists in the array.

For example, if you have a 4-core processor, then each thread has an outer loop that uses 1/4 of the array. That should speed things up by a factor of four, which reduces your run time to about 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

Are any of the values negative?  Can you keep a record of the maximum and minimum values encountered during input?  (Answer: yes; it is easy to do that.  You can use that to eliminate the inner loop if the outer loops identify 2 values that cannot add up to the target.)

Suppose you have N numbers. You then can decide that you can split the workload between 3 threads so that (for example, pulling fractions out of thin air):

- thread 1 will work the outer loop for indexes 0 to N/5;
- thread 2 will work the outer loop for indexes N/5+1 to N/3; and
- thread 3 will work the outer loop for indexes N/3+1 to N.

The middle loops will start at the outer loop index plus one, and if there could be a solution, the inner loops will start at the middle index plus one.

The reason for the asymmetric partitioning is that the first thread will be examining more values in the middle and inner loops than the other threads will.  In fact, I expect that I've not skewed the workload enough — the `5` should quite probably be a bigger number, and the 3 should be bigger too, and so on.  And if you have more threads, the calculation gets trickier.  You want to roughly balance the workload for each thread.

If you specify the fraction of the range of the outer loop for each thread as F1, F2, F3, then:

- thread 1 will work C1 = (N/F1)•(N-1)•(N-2) tests.
- thread 2 will work C2 = (N/F2)•(N-N/F1-1)•(N-N/F1-2) tests.
- thread 3 will work C3 = (N/F3)•(N-N/F1-N/F2-1)•(N-N/F1-N/F2-2) tests.

and you want C1 ≈ C2 ≈ C3.  The generalization to *m* threads is fairly clear; the solution is not.  You can change the nomenclature to use a multiplicative fraction of the range, or to specify [L1..U1] for thread 1, and [L2..U2] for thread 2, and [L3..U3] for thread 3, subject to L2 = U1 + 1, L3 = U2 + 1, and [L1..U3] covers the whole range N, etc.

Answer (score 0):

We can use multithreading in the following way as well:

```
int save_num[3][8]; //To give a different cache line
omp_set_num_threads(3); Set number of threads as 3 
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i< 10000; i++){
 int local_sum = file[i];
 int thread = omp_get_thread_num();
 save_num[thread][1]=local_sum;
#pragma omp critical
 if(save_num[0][1] + save_num[1][1] + save_num[2][1] ==233) {
  break;
 }
}
```

I haven't tested this code. Although the logic would remain the same. This would run it in three threads and enter the critical section only once and check if the condition is true while saving the three numbers in the `save_num` variable.